# settings a google maps LatLng value Javascrjpt

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm developing an Android application where the code to set up the Google Maps API is done in Java, however I am trying to use an API to call a method written in the backend in node.js to create new google maps LatLng values, however when I try:

```
app.post('/simulate', async(req, result) => {
        const postData = req.body;
        const lat = postData.lat;
        const lng = postData.lng;
        var i = 0;
        const coordinates = [];
        while(i<50000) {
            const latitude = getRandomInRange(-90, 90, 5);
            const longitude = getRandomInRange(-180, 180, 5);

            const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            coordinates.push(latLng);
            i++;
        }
        console.log(coordinates);
        result.send(coordinates);

    })
```

the new google.maps.LatLng cannot be found, how can i get around this?

Comment: perhaps providing examples of failed lat/lngs would help. Also the `getRandomInRange` function. When you say `"cannot be found"` - presumably Google complains that these are not valid coordinates?

Comment: It's not that the lat/lngs are failing, it's that the google.maps.LatLng is of an unresolved variable type. how can I 'import' google maps LatLngs into the project?

Comment: So that is more a Java issue than Node/Javascript?

Comment: No it's javascript, I can't use the google.maps.LatLng type, I'm not exactly sure what I am missing..

Comment: presumably then you have all the correct libraries at your project's disposal? [Google Maps for Node.js](https://github.com/googlemaps/google-maps-services-js)